# Combining Post Thumbnails With Nivo Slider

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am wanting to use the post thumbnail with the nivo slider and for it to generate the image from a custom image size (already declared in my functions file)

I wrote this (for generating the images)

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" data-thumb=""<?php the_post_thumbnail('sliderimage')> title="" />
```

It doesnt seem to load the images, however if i take away the image tags etc it works.

Can the above be achieved this way so that it auto generates the thumbnails and loads the images?

Answer (score 0):

`the_post_thumbnail()` *displays* the featured image.  [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) retrieves it for use in code.  Try something like this:

```
<?php
$featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() );
$fi_src = $featured_image['src'];
$slider = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'sliderimage' );
$s_src = $slider['src'];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $fi_src; ?>" data-thumb=""<?php echo $s_src; ?> title="" />
```

Comment: Hi Pat i tried this at it came up with a fatal error:  undefined function get_post_thumbnail()

Comment: i posted the featured image bit into my functions and the other bit into my sidebar file

Comment: Whoops, it's `get_the_post_thumbnail()`, not `get_post_thumbnail()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: hi pat, its coming up with a forbidden error now... is it the case i cant hardcode this in wordpress unlike the plugin you can prebuy?

Comment: im assuming i add this whole code to my sidebar, as adding the first part to the functions didnt pull the image :S

Comment: i removed the get bit and it generated the main image, but not the thumbnails and did something trippy lol! :S

Comment: Forbidden error? Not sure what you mean. Also, not sure what "something trippy" might be.  Is `sliderimage` a defined size in your theme/plugin?

Comment: basically in the console, where i can see errors its coming up with an error saying forbidden. And slider image is defined :(